# RegEx - Anything to be not captured between groups in an HTML-Anchor Element

Tags: java, regex

So I'm trying to modify a RegEx to capture tags inside an HTML-Anchor element (I know you're not supposed to, but it is demanded). But a problem arose when I tried to to not match anything inbetween the capture-groups since the "anything" is taken literally and so the tags inside the element aren't captured. Until now I have tried a non-capturing group and a negated set but both seem to "swallow" my groups.

```
/<a[^>]*href=\"([^\"]+)\"(?:.*?)( data-survey=[\"\']({[^}]*})[\"\'])?( data-answer=[\"\']({[^}]*})[\"\'])?[^>]*\/?>/g
```

The `(?:.*?)` seems to be the culprit here. For example: `<a href="#" foo data-survey="{...}">`. As long as there isn't anything inbetween the `<a` and the `data...` it seems to be working.

Comment: You should look into using Java's XML parsing capabilities.  Using regex to parse HTML is not the most optimal thing to be doing.

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)
HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.

Comment: `[^>]*` is better than `.*?`, so a prior `<a` will not match upto this one (primariy inefficient).

Comment: @JoopEggen: They are not strictly equivalent, `[^>]*` matches linebreaks and `.*?` doesn't without `s` flag.

Comment: @Toto _indeed_, though `<a \n href="...">` is valid though rare HTML.

Comment: XPath is reasonably simple and will be easier to maintain than half-broken regular expressions. Use that to query xml data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing that problematic:

```
(?:.*?)
```

with:

```
(?:(?! data-(?:survey=|answer=)).)*
```

which says to keep matching the next character as long as the next characters are not `' data-survey='` or `' data-answer='`.

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WDTYIl/3/)

Comment: Had to change it to ```(?:(?! data-|>).)*``` so it doesn't match too much when it encounters only an ```<a href="#" />```, but this worked. Thank you!

Comment: Changed it to make sure it a bit more robust.

Comment: I think what you had originally would have worked if `data-survey="etc.` were not optional.